# GPG key exists in the list?

Tags: bash, shell, gnupg

I want to create a shell script and I haven't worked with it before. 
There is a command for gpg:

```
gpg --keyserver SERVER --recv-keys  KEY
```

The problem is that I don't want to run this command if key has been already added. Is there any method to check that key exists in keys list?
Thank you!

Comment: Anything wrong with `gpg -k`?

Comment: You mean: gpg -k | grep KEY ?

Comment: Would be an idea, wouldn't it?

Comment: I thought that there would be more elegant way :-)

Comment: Why should it? Check if the return value of said operation is empty (or, if you don't need the key, whether the grep returns a non-zero exit code) and execute the loading of the gpg key only then. Imho, bash scripts are most elegant when they do their job most effectively, both in execution and programming time.

Comment: `gpg -k` doesn't check for all keys in the system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run `gpg --list-keys [key-id]` (or the abbreviated command `-k`), which will have a return code of 0 (success) if a matching key exists, or something else (failure) otherwise. Don't list all keys and `grep` afterwards as proposed by others in the comments, this will get *horribly* slow for larger numbers of keys in the keyring. Run

```
gpg --list-keys [key-id] || gpg --keyserver [server] --recv-keys [key-id]
```

to fetch missing keys, possibly discarding the first `gpg` call's output (`gpg --list-keys [key-id]  >/dev/null 2>&1 || ...`), as you're only interested in the return code.

Be aware that

- updating keys from time to time might be a reasonable thing to do to fetch revocations
- especially [short key IDs should never be used](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74009/what-is-an-openpgp-key-id-collision/74010#74010), use the whole fingerprint if possible.

Comment: `gpg --list-keys` doesn't list all keys.

Comment: `gpg --list-keys` lists all keys available in the _currently used keyring_. If the key is in whichever other keyring, this won't help you at using it. `apt-key list` will only list keys in the apt package manager's keyring -- this does not seem to be what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
[[ $(gpg --list-keys | grep -w KEY) ]] && echo "Key exists" ||
gpg --keyserver SERVER --recv-keys  KEY
```

Additional (for apt keyring):

```
[[ $(apt-key list | grep -w KEY) ]] && echo "Key exists" ||
gpg --keyserver SERVER --recv-keys  KEY
```

If `apt-key` is available

Comment: Be aware  that `apt-key` only works on the `apt` package manager's keyring, and not the user's one. This is very likely not what the OP intends to do.

Comment: @JensErat, it seems I misinterpreted OP's intention. `gpg --list-keys` is the way to go

Comment: Some years later, apt-key is deprecated https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/apt-key.8.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is running the following command

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com -k [your-key-id]`